# How do I set a text file's title to be a variable in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I want to try to allow the user of a batch file to create their own text file, using a custom title for the text file. The problem I am having is that the text file that is trying to be created doesn't get created. Here is what I have done:

```
Echo Title your book.
set /p BookTitle=
>"%BookTitle% | by: %PlayerName%.txt" echo %Story%
```

Comment: DOS and Windows do not permit colons (`:`) in filenames or directory names.

Comment: The pipe (`|`) is also going to seriously mess up things. Use a caret (`^`) to escape it.

Comment: Wait, I misread what you were trying to use as the filename. You can't include the pipe at all. Just avoid using it altogether.

Comment: thanks, I will not use the pipe, or the colon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get @SomethingDark suggestion to use `^|` to work, but by removing the `:` and replacing `|` with `_` or `-` your batch works fine.

The `|` character is invalid for filenames in Windows [MSDN: Naming, Files and Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
echo Title your book.
set /p BookTitle=
>"%BookTitle% _ by %PlayerName%.txt" echo %Story%
```

Comment: You may also have to escape the escape (`^^^|`) if `^|` doesn't work.

Comment: Have tried the double escape - thanks for the suggestion - although have now found this is swimming upstream against valid filename characters (edited with MSDN article).

Comment: For some reason, my brain refused to accept that he was trying to use the pipe as part of the filename. Personally, I would name the files `%PlayerName% - %BookTitle%.txt` or better yet, make a `%PlayerName%` folder and put `%BookTitle%.txt` inside of it.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, my problem is now solved!